# SQL Query Error

Tags: windows, sql-server, mysql, sql

Trying to perform a query on a group of network servers, but getting an odd syntax error.  The top query will run successfully, but as soon as the Add/Remove Progs is added, "The multi-part identifier "SYS.ResourceID" could not be bound."  In the end I want to be able to query a group of computers and view the Add/Remove Program list from each one.

Working Code to pull server type, service pack, etc:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SYS.Name, OPSYS.Caption0, OPSYS.CSDVersion0, OPSYS.InstallDate0,OPSYS.LastBootUpTime0
FROM v_FullCollectionMembership SYS
JOIN v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM OPSYS on SYS.ResourceID=OPSYS.ResourceID
WHERE SYS.CollectionID = @CollID
ORDER BY SYS.Name,OPSYS.Caption0
```

Not working:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SYS.Name, OPSYS.Caption0, OPSYS.CSDVersion0, OPSYS.InstallDate0,OPSYS.LastBootUpTime0, ARP.DisplayName0, ARP.Version0
FROM v_FullCollectionMembership SYS ,  v_Add_Remove_Programs ARP
JOIN v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM OPSYS on SYS.ResourceID=OPSYS.ResourceID
WHERE SYS.CollectionID = @CollID
ORDER BY SYS.Name,OPSYS.Caption0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMS 2003, eh?

I don't see where you're joining against the v_Add_Remove_Programs (as ARP) table. You're going to have to name it in a join.

Totally off the cuff, this should work (but probably won't... *smile*  I don't have this schema sitting around to query):

```
SELECT DISTINCT SYS.Name, OPSYS.Caption0, OPSYS.CSDVersion0, OPSYS.InstallDate0,OPSYS.LastBootUpTime0, ARP.DisplayName0, ARP.Version0
FROM v_FullCollectionMembership SYS
INNER JOIN v_GS_OPERATING_SYSTEM OPSYS on SYS.ResourceID = OPSYS.ResourceID
INNER JOIN v_Add_Remove_Programs ARP on SYS.ResourceID = ARP.ResourceID
WHERE SYS.CollectionID = @CollID
ORDER BY SYS.Name,OPSYS.Caption0
```

Comment: that works great - now is there a way to hide redundant data (such as multiple Name/CSD Version/etc from the query?  As in have 1 server name, then the installed programs....and then the next server name and its programs...

Comment: as with Evan, I don't know the schema, the "ORDER BY SYS.Name" should list each system in order, but I know SQL doesn't always follow ORDER BY directives. If not, your best bet may be to put the data in Excel or OpenOffice and manually sort.

Comment: You can "hide" the "redundant" data by using a reporting engine (Crystal, Access, Datavision, etc) to process the output of the query. You're essentially talking about having a report a detail section grouped by some criteria. You're not going to get that out of an SQL query.